# WPF: Adding Shapes to a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a List that I want to draw on a canvas.  The problem I am having is getting the shapes to draw relative to the other shapes.  Right now I basically have 4 right triangles that when correctly combined for a diamond:

```
 /| |\
--- ---

--- ---
 \| |/
```

The problem I am having is that all of the triangles get drawn on top of each other.  How do I add Geometry objects to a canvas so that they are laid out correctly relative to each other and still scale to the canvas as a group?

```
foreach (var g in GetAListOfGeometries())
{
   System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new Path();
   path.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
   path.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Purple;
   path.StrokeThickness = 1;
   path.Data = g;

   canvas.Children.Add((Geometry)path);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left attached properties.

For example:

```
Canvas.SetTop(path, 10);
Canvas.SetLeft(path, 10);
```

More information about attached properties can be found here: [Attached Properties MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)